# React Router Dom Nested Show Blank Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a path so that only an administrator user can access.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route
          path="/*"
          element={
            <PublicRoutes>
              <DashboardRoutes />
            </PublicRoutes>
          }
        />
        //is the following
        <Route
          path="/admin"
          element={
            <PrivateRoutes>
              <AdminRoutes />
            </PrivateRoutes>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

In PrivateRoutes, I verify that the user is admin. The function VerifyAdmin() returns true or false checking the role of the user with the payload

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({ children }) => {
  const hasAccess = () => {
    let allowed = false;
    let hasToken = localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false;
    if(hasToken){
      allowed = VerifyAdmin()
    }
    return allowed
  };
  return hasAccess() ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
};
```

This is the admin routes:

```
const AdminRoutes = () => {
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
      <Route path="/admin/games" element={<GamesList />} />
      <Route path="/admin/games/add" element={<GameForm />} />
      <Route path="/admin/users" element={<UsersList />} />
      <Route path="/admin/users/add" element={<UserForm />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  </>;
};
```

If the user is not admin, it redirects him and prevents him from accessing the component. In case of being an administrator, it loads the component, but it loads blank nothing can be seen on the page, everything is blank.

Why does this happen and what can I do? help me please! :(

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: Im using the 6.3.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdminRoutes` is rendering an additional `Routes` and ***descendent*** routes, so the parent route must append the `"*"` wildcard matcher to the admin route.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/admin/*"
  element={
    <PrivateRoutes>
      <AdminRoutes />
    </PrivateRoutes>
  }
/>
```

See [How do I nest routes deep in the tree](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree).

The `AdminRoutes` component will render its routes relative to the ancestor route though, so it should remove the `"/admin"` path prefix.

Example:

```
const AdminRoutes = () => {
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Admin />} />
      <Route path="/games" element={<GamesList />} />
      <Route path="/games/add" element={<GameForm />} />
      <Route path="/users" element={<UsersList />} />
      <Route path="/users/add" element={<UserForm />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  </>;
};
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question, I just tried it, but the same thing happens, the page loads in white

Comment: @duck_go19 Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-nested-show-blank-page-z7lizg?file=/src/App.js) demo with your code and my answer applied working as I'd expect. Can you check it out?

Comment: Mysteriously creating a new file and writing the code there solved it, it's very strange but it finally works. Thanks a lot for your help